# show product list by store id magento

Tags: magento-1.6

I have problem to show product list on magento. My current code only shows filter by category:

Example:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="18" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

I only want it to filter by store id

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" store_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

This doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. You will need to modify / override the product listing block.

copy

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

to

/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php

You would need to modify **_getProductCollection()**

You could add something like this

```
if($this->getStoreId()) {
    $this->_productCollection->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());
}
```

$this->getStoreId() will pull through the value you use in your tag: store_id="3"